# hadoop: change replication factor of a specific block rather than of a file

Tags: hadoop, replication-factor

Is it possible to change the replication factor of a specific block of a file rather than changing it for (all blocks of) a file?

I am new to Hadoop but I understand that we can change replication factor a file by

```
1.hadoop fs -setrep -w -R replication_factor file_name

2.using the setReplication()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. You can only change replication for a file, directory or blocks.

[Source](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Replica_Placement:_The_First_Baby_Steps)

Answer (score 0):

`Replication` of a `block` would be possible, if we know the mechanism of knowing the block metadata (information) that needs replication.

And since dividing input data to blocks and distribution is a dynamic process and storage of block location in `Namenode` is not static, its not possible to replicate only one block (as that block can never be determined)

Even if we define our own mechanism to identify block location from metadata stored in `Namenode`, the algorithm would be useful for only that particular input.

So I guess your requirement is not possible in the current state.